# Editing and closing in the close queue

Tags: support, editing, vote-to-close

When edit a question in the close queue, it automatically skips to the next question. So I have to open the question in a new tab to VTC.

Is there any direct way to achive this?

Or is there any particular reason why this cannot be done?

Answer (score 6):

I find this annoying too.  I often see a question that should be cleaned up AND closed.  I recently re-read the [close-vote guidance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to figure this out.  This is the pertinent few sentences:

> Editing the question or gathering enough Leave Open votes will automatically kick the question out of the queue and immediately begin aging the close votes (no matter the number of views). If the question receives another close vote after being kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review. Questions with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible duplicate in a tab at the top for easy reviewing.

It seems editing is viewed as an implicit "leave open" vote.  I assume the rational behind that is that if the question is worth closing it isn't worth editing and if it is worth editing, it's worth leaving open.

The way I've been handling this is to open a new tab, edit the question, and then cast a close vote.

I do this because I want our closed questions to be searchable so that in the future we can find them for duplicate marking or even to help discourage more poor questions from being asked by new users.

Comment: I use a new tab as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the "edit" buttons placed in the review queues are meant to bring the question back into our scope. Because, it has popped into the review queue due to its *off-topicness* or its low quality or some flags.

And so far (in my 3k user lifetime), I've done the same believing my hypothesis...